# Cloud Build Failing to add values from Secret Manager to environment variable

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I am trying to use values from secret manager in my cloud-build step.
However the secret values are not passed correctly to the dockerfile and subsequently to the python scripts. How should I make sure the WEBAPP and the GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT  values are available for the python functions in my term-forecasts directory

Here is the cloudbuild.yaml Step

```
steps
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    id: "build-search-term-forecast-image"
    args:
      - "build"
      - '--build-arg'
      - 'WEBAPP=$$WEBAPP'
      - '--build-arg'
      - 'GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT=${PROJECT_ID}'
      - "-t"
      - "${FORECASTS_IMAGE}"
      - "-f"
      - "./term-forecasts/Dockerfile"
      - "./term-forecasts/"
    secretEnv: [ 'WEBAPP' ]
images:
  - "${FORECASTS_IMAGE}"

options:
  dynamicSubstitutions: true
  automapSubstitutions: true

substitutions:
  _DATABASE_PORT: 'us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/${PROJECT_ID}/forecasts-repo/get-forecasts'

availableSecrets:
  secretManager:
    - versionName: projects/$PROJECT_ID/secrets/WEBAPP/versions/latest
      env: WEBAPP
```

Here is the Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.11-slim-buster
ARG GT_WEBAPP
ARG GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT

ENV GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT=$GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT
ENV WEBAPP=$WEBAPP


WORKDIR /app

RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip --no-cache-dir

COPY requirements.txt /app/
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY main.py /app/

# Consider using a non-root user to run your application (for security)
RUN useradd -m image_user
USER image_user

CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```

Here is my python file

```py
PROJECT_ID = os.getenv('GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT')
web_url = os.getenv('WEBAPP')
```

When I try to access the web_url, it comes as
`$WEBAPP` and not the actual url

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the correct arg name. it's GT_WEBAPP in your container. Try that in Cloud Build

```
steps
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    id: "build-search-term-forecast-image"
    args:
      - "build"
      - '--build-arg'
      - 'GT_WEBAPP=$$WEBAPP' # Updated line
      - '--build-arg'
      - 'GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT=${PROJECT_ID}'
      - "-t"
      - "${FORECASTS_IMAGE}"
      - "-f"
      - "./term-forecasts/Dockerfile"
      - "./term-forecasts/"
    secretEnv: [ 'WEBAPP' ]
images:
  - "${FORECASTS_IMAGE}"
...
```

Keep in mind that a container is simply a packaging mode, without any security and encryption. Therefore, your secrets will be stored in plain text in your container. Do not set real secret like that!

Comment: Even with the corrected name, the docker file does not recognize the GT_WEBAPP and returns it as $GT_WEBAPP. What would be the best way to deal with these secrets? Create a script within the Python file?

Comment: It's better to load secret at runtime. Where you you run this container?

Comment: I run the container in a VM in GCP. But going the route of adding code directly in the scripts to access the secrets sounds like a good idea.